# RewriteCond "except for directory" failing in complex rule set

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internet-explorer-8

I need to force **everything** except IE8 to HTTPS and IE8 specifically to HTTP 
(it's temporarily - hence the 302 - its stupid, but there are legit business reasons).

I want all of this to ignore the `/api/` directory as the app that utilizes these sadly doesn't follow redirects.

The following is working, IE8 detection is working. Everything is **except** `/api/whatever` is still being redirected.

I'd really appreciate any advice or an explanation of why this is not working.

```
# make sure mod_rewrite is ON
    RewriteEngine On

# force staging and live to SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    # Unless its IE 8
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !compatible;\sMSIE\s8\.0 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|staging\.)?example\.com [NC]
    # Skip the API
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*
    # 301 Permanent
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force IE8 to Non-SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} compatible;\sMSIE\s8\.0 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|staging\.)?example\.com [NC]
    # Skip the API
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*
    # 302 Temporary
    RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Comment: what do you mean app doesn't follow redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*` was working, the problem was a later rewrite routing everything through a front controller /index.php was causing the htaccess to reparse.

Changing the rule to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/api/|/index.php)` solved the problem.  the front controller, index.php isn't callable directly anyway, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong, though assuming that you've cleared your browser's cache, you could try a different approach and include an explicit pass-through at the top of your list of rules:

```
RewriteRule ^api/ - [L]
```

You can add that right under `RewriteEngine On` and get rid of the `/api` conditions.

Comment: I am testing using curl from the command line so I don't believe I need to worry about caching at all.